# Html Input type File working on Android webview - a working example?

Tags: android, html, file, input, webview

it's been a week since i'm looking for a solution to bypass the block on the android webview to simple pick up a file (client side) from a device to upload on a server.

I've read all the posts on StackOverflow but **can't find a working solution**. Many solutions are on android program language, not HTML!

**Can someone suggest a working example??** i'm going crazy about that (a simple form that works on iOs and on mobile Chrome browser but not on webview based on Chromium!!).

Comment: `read all the posts on StackOverflow`. Well where were they talking about? What is the exact problem?

Comment: All the posts that talk about the problem don't solve it!. The problem is the input type="file" process that not works in webview. I think i need an external code that allow user to access to his device stored file (like input file do), but an html version (not in java android language!).

Comment: `that not works in webview. `. Well that is only half the story. It used to work in webview. What changed?

Comment: Works?? I load a html page with a simple form with **input type file** into a webview but when i click on "select file" nothing happend!
I'm working on a hibrid app and this process works if i open this app in iOs devices (i can access to my device's library) but not on Android devices.

Comment: I said that it used to work. You can read that in the posts you read too. I asked you to tell what changed meanwhile.

Comment: **input type file** don't works!! like title says - i need i working example (a link of a page to test opening in android webview), if someone has solve it!